# OpenOffice Calc "if" formula for currencies

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, currency-format

I have a spreadsheet that has many different currencies in it ($, euro, shekel).  I want to display the actual price in the original currency and then show the converted price (in this case to shekels).  I found a formula for it using [excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/433609-if-formula-against-currency-signs.html#post2141447), but when I try to use it in openoffice it doesn't work, I get a 508 error.  Here's the formula I came up with:

```
=IF(LEFT(D12, 1)="$";D12*Conversions.C4;IF(LEFT(D12, 1) = "€";D12*Conversions.B4; D12))
```

Where D12 is the cell with the original price, Conversions.C4 is the cell to convert $ to shekels and Conversions.B4 is the cell to convert euros to shekels.

As an aside and bonus points, if anyone knows how to plug in a continually updated currency conversion formula (instead of having to look up and manually change the rate every week/month/whatever), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [Calc Error Codes](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes): 508  Error: Pair missing "For example, closing parenthesis without opening parenthesis

or missing closing parenthesis in the middle of the formula (missing
closing parenthesis at the end of a formula is added automatically)."

Comment: On the aside, googling "excel currency converter" returns links to free Excel plugins that do currency conversion (and update the exchange rates periodically), a downloadable Excel spreadsheet with updated rates, and various other interesting articles on currency conversion in Excel. Will Any of those work in OpenOffice Calc? No clue, but they may be a place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for quoting that, David.  I had already seen that and checked and I didn't see anyplace where I was missing a parenthesis.  If you see it, please let me know where it is.  I was thinking there was something more sinister at play here, like the idea that the test LEFT(D12, 1)="$" simply didn't work in openoffice.  any ideas?   BLM, thank you very much for that direction.

Comment: it may be that the currecny is is just "shown" by format, while the cell itself  only contains a numerical value... have u checked that?

Comment: Dirk, thank you for that.  I was assuming that was the case and then I found the excel solution with testing the left-most character.  But even if it's just the formatting and it doesn't change the contents of the cell at all, certainly there should be a way to test the formatting and run an if-statement based on that, no?  At this point if I don't find something soon I'm going to have to use excel, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 1):

The error code is caused by using commas in the `LEFT` function where semicolons are needed (OpenOffice requires semicolons in most places that Excel uses commas).

In addition, as pointed out in the comments to this question, OpenOffice sees a number with currency formatting as just a number and the `LEFT` function will only return numbers from that cell.

To work around this, use Text to Columns to convert all currency numbers to text.  Either on the original data, or on a copy in another column or sheet if you need to maintain the formatting as numbers on the original.

Highlight all the currency cells you are going to convert to text.  Select Data→Text to Columns.  At the bottom of the popup window, click on the column of cells you are converting to highlight them.  Select column type "Text".  Repeat if you are converting multiple columns.  Click the OK button to perform the conversion.

Now your original formula will give a new error code because it objects to doing math on a text string.  To fix this use the function `VALUE` to convert back to a number where necessary:

```
=IF(LEFT(D12; 1)="$";VALUE(D12)*Conversions.C4;IF(LEFT(D12; 1) = "€";VALUE(D12)*Conversions.B4; D12))
```

Comment: Lyrl, thank you very much!  That explains a lot.  But I have a complication.  The spreadsheet is intended to be a collaborative project.  Is it possible to have a formula that would continually convert the data to text?  Alternatively if anyone knows of how to do it in google docs spreadsheet, we've been thinking of transferring it to that as well.  Again, thanks!

Comment: How is the data being entered?  If by hand, if you set the Format of the column to Text before entering any data, all the values will be text to start out with.  If you're importing from a CSV file, you can choose column type of Text in the import dialog.  If you need both number and text copies: I'm not aware of any function to convert a number, including display formatting, into text, but the `VALUE` function converts text into numbers.  You could enter the items as text and have a column with `VALUE` formulas to get a separate column with equivalent numbers.